# Can i exchange my arduino nano for an atmega328p-pu in my project?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-nano, atmega328

Im currently trying to make a smart light switcher that is attached in front of my rooms light switches. It basically mostly consists of two servos (to turn on or off either switch), two button (to turn the servo manually), an esp8266 esp-01 module (to be able to use with a google home) and my arduino nano. I really need to make it as small as posible and i also want to keep my only arduino not attached to the wall. Would it work if i use an atmega328p or like an attiny84a to replace the arduino?

Im not finished with connecting the esp-01 to the arduino but i was thinking of using the arduino's 3.3v output pin. Would i need extra components to run the microcontroller on its own?

Im really new to arduino and im trying to learn the most I can and to try to make my little project as good as i can.

Would really appreciate some help please, thank you!

Comment: [This article](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone) might help you. It is specially for the Atmega328p and for setting up the complete Arduino, but it explains all the important things

Comment: The 3.3V output is on the board.  You’re not going to get that from the chip   The chip doesn’t have its own regulator.  I doubt the 3V3 pin could push an ESP anyway.  They pull a good bit of current.

Comment: ESP-01 could consumed as much as 170mA burst, all the Arduino Boards (I only have Leonardio, Nano and Pro Micro) that I have can't supply enough current for the ESP-01.

Comment: I use a Pro Mini with a ESP-01 that sit on a tiny self-made 30x23mm adaptor board which includes a LDO regulator for powering both the Pro Mini and ESP-01. Instead of trying to use bare-bone ATMega328p, just get a Pro Mini, it is probably cheaper and not much bigger than the bare-bone when you add the crystal and other components.

Comment: Hi @hcheung, would you mind showing how you made your project or where you found the information of connecting the ESP-01 to a Pro Mini? I decided to buy the board since its smaller but im still not sure how to use the module. Thanks

Comment: Pro Mini is just like a Nano, except it does not has the USB interface and you have to use a USB-TTl adaptor to upload Arduino Sketch. For ESP-01, I forked a [library](https://github.com/e-tinkers/LiteESP8266Client) that utilising AT Command communication between Pro Mini and ESP-01. But on a recent project, I use a hybrid approach for both ESP-01 and an STM32 boards running Arduino sketch and communicate via serial, you can read about my approach at [here](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/04/a-better-way-to-use-esp-01-as-wifi-shield/).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can - as long as you include the rest of the support circuitry.

However the ESP-01 beats the Arduino hands-down and can do everything the Arduino does by itself - except it lacks IO so connecting to the servo and button could be tricky.

So using some kind of extra MCU as an IO expansion over serial would be a good idea, but a 328P is rather more than you need. Maybe you should look at something smaller, such as one of the ATTiny chips.